# Does Lion allow locking screen on computer sleep and screen saver but not display sleep?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, sleep-wake, screensaver, screen-lock

In Leopard, you can configure it so that a password is required when waking the system from computer sleep (i.e. close the lid) or returning from the screen saver, but not display sleep. This allowed me to easily lock my screen by activating the screen saver with a hot corner or have it lock automatically after an extended period of time when the screen saver kicked in or the machine went to sleep.

In Snow Leopard, however, this changed to require a password even for display sleep. This is frustrating because I'd have constantly type my password. A detailed discussion of the issue is [available on Apple's forum](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10134937).

I'd like to know if Lion 'fixed' this problem? Or does it behave the same as in Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lion has "fixed" the problem by changing the wording of the preference, not by changing the behaviour. It now says "Require password <pulldown list of times> after sleep or screen saver begins".

Comment: Sigh. Why Apple? Why?